# Incorrect code to check if a word can be made of smaller given words (word break)

Tags: c, algorithm, trie

Incorrect code to check if a word can be made of smaller given words (word break).This is the code I wrote for the above mentioned problem, however an online judge declares it as incorrect, what could be the possible reasons? And how should I modify my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Node structure */
typedef struct node {
    int letter[26];
    struct node* next[26];
    int is_word;
} node;


/* Create node   */
node* getnode(void) {
    node* p = malloc(sizeof(node));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1004; i++) {
        p->letter[i] = 0;
        p->next[i] = NULL;
    }
    p->is_word = 0;

    return p;
}

/* make dictionary  */
void fill_dictionary(char word[], node* start) {
    int len = strlen(word), i;
    node* temp = start;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (temp->letter[word[i] % 'a'] == 0) {
            temp->letter[word[i] % 'a'] = 1;
            temp->next[word[i] % 'a'] = getnode();
            temp = temp->next[word[i] % 'a'];
        } else {
            temp = temp->next[word[i] % 'a'];
        }
    }

    temp->is_word = 1;
    return;
}

int spell_check(char line[100003], node* start) {
    int len = strlen(line), i, flag = 0;
    node* temp = start;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (temp->letter[line[i] % 'a'] == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            temp = temp->next[line[i] % 'a'];
            flag = 0;

            if (temp->is_word == 1) {
                flag = 1;
                temp = start;
            }
        }
    }

    if (flag == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n, i, ans, m;
    scanf("%d %d", &n,&m);  // no. of words in dictionary
    node* start = getnode();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char word[11];      // max length of dictionary word
        scanf("%s", word);
        fill_dictionary(word, start);
    }

    scanf("%d", &n);        // no. of lines to be checked

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char line[100003];  // max length of a line
        scanf("%s", line);
        ans = spell_check(line, start);

        if (ans == 0) {
            printf("YES\n");
        } else {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i < 1004`, `p -> letter[i] = 0;` out of bounds.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  for                                                                                inputs                                                                                                      3 6
sur
suresh
esho
1
sursursureshsursuresho                                                                            The code's giving NO, even though it should be YES, what could be the reason?

Comment: The operation of the incorrect program.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no after changing i<1004 to i<26 I got the wrong answer for above query

Comment: `word[i] % 'a'` --> aChar % 97 => range of result is 0-96 (case of unsigned char). out of range(0-25).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Could you please help modify the code? Sorry I am a beginner at this.

Comment: you think again by yourself.

Comment: @nerdistcolony It's indented now I think.

Comment: What is `m`? Does the problem statement make you input a value tgat is not subsequently used?

Comment: http://ideone.com/Q4DPVb Post your test data.

Comment: m is the largest length of any of the substrings, the question needs me to accept it.

Comment: Tell what works and doesn't work in the code after applying @BLUEPIXY's suggestions. Too much to try to guess what the 'judge' didn't like or thought was incorrect. What is incorrect?

Comment: @nerdistcolony if one substring is contained in another substring, then it leads to problems. Example abcdefghj, def

Input example 
 3 6 
sur 
suresh 
esho 
1 
sursursureshsursuresho

gives output as NO instead of YES

Comment: Just some suggestions - you don't need comments if they just basically say what the function name describes. Just make the function name as clear and perfectly accurate a summary as possible and only add comments if you need to clarify stuff like parameter use or complicated functionality that isn't easily discerned by looking at the code.  When you get better you can see what code is doing pretty quickly and a well designed function with a good name and well-named/designed arguments is usually self-explanatory.

Comment: Never use magic numbers like 1004 or 26 or 100003. Always name them like const keyword, or enum, or #define ALPHABET_LETTER_COUNT 26, or MAX_LINES, etc... Arbitrary literal numbers like that is a no-no. For one thing it's harder to update the program if you do that. With a constant you can change it in one place. And people can see by reading it exactly what it is without having to study the code or guess what or why you did it.  Also, if you don't need to put a fixed size on something, don't. Use null-terminated lists, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to to it. This compiles and runs. It displays the parsed result. It tries to read the dictionary from a file called "dictionary.text" in the current directory. You can change it to put the dictionary wherever you want.  I commented it heavily to help you understand it but it has some subtle C things you may need to really think about and figure out.  One bit of advice: Name *everything* in a program as extremely accurately for what it is/does as possible (but reasonably succinct). That will help immensely when trying to debug or figure out what you did wrong. Careless names really make code confusing and hard to debug.

Good luck!

Example:

$ gcc -o wordsplitter wordsplitter.c

$ wordsplitter xyzhellogoodbyefoodogcatpigcarwhereareyouhorse

**xyz "hello" "goodbye" foo "dog" "cat" pigcar "where" "are" "you" horse**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DICTIONARY_FILEPATH  "dictionary.txt"
#define MAX_WORD_SIZE  100
/*
 * Error codes (usually this is put in a header file and included)
 */
#define SUCCESS         0
#define FILE_NOT_FOUND -1
#define OUT_OF_MEMORY  -2

typedef struct word {
    struct word *next;
    char *word;
} word_t;

word_t *dictionaryListhead = NULL;

typedef struct wordsubcomponent {
    struct wordsubcomponent *next;
    char *text;
    int isDictionaryWord;
} wordsubcomponent_t;

int
loadDictionaryFromFile(char *filename, word_t **listhead)
{
    char wordFromFile[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
    word_t *lastWordStored = NULL;

    FILE *dictionaryFile = fopen(filename, "r"); 
    if (dictionaryFile == NULL) {
        return FILE_NOT_FOUND;
    }    
    while(fgets(wordFromFile, sizeof(wordFromFile), dictionaryFile)) {
        word_t *newDictionaryWordNode;
        if ((newDictionaryWordNode = calloc(sizeof(word_t), 1)) == NULL) { // calloc automatically zeroes memory
            return OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        }
        char *cp = strchr(wordFromFile, '\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = '\0'; // get rid of trailing \n

        newDictionaryWordNode->word = strdup(wordFromFile);     
        if (*listhead == NULL) {
            lastWordStored = *listhead = newDictionaryWordNode;
        } else {
            lastWordStored = lastWordStored->next = newDictionaryWordNode;
        }
    }
    fclose(dictionaryFile);
    return SUCCESS;
}

wordsubcomponent_t 
*newsubcomponent() {
    wordsubcomponent_t *subcomp = NULL;
    if ((subcomp = calloc(sizeof(wordsubcomponent_t), 1)) != NULL) { 
        subcomp->text = strdup("");  // seed with empty string (instead of NULL) so we can append
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory (fatal). program exiting\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return subcomp;
}

/*
 * Returns an linked list of word subcomponents for the given word, split up around dictionary words
 */
wordsubcomponent_t *getWordSubcomponents(char *wordToParse, word_t *listhead) {
    wordsubcomponent_t *subcomponents, *currSubcomp;
    subcomponents = currSubcomp = newsubcomponent();
    for (char *cp = wordToParse; cp < wordToParse + strlen(wordToParse);) { // exit when cp gets to end of word to parse.
        int matchFlag = 0;
        for (word_t *wordNode = listhead; wordNode != NULL; wordNode = wordNode->next) {
            if (strncasecmp(cp, wordNode->word, strlen(wordNode->word)) == 0) { // prefix of cur. ptr is dict word.
                if (strlen(currSubcomp->text) != 0) // Detected non-dict text in subcomp.
                    currSubcomp = currSubcomp->next = newsubcomponent(); // leave in list & add new subcomp for dict word.
                currSubcomp->text = wordNode->word; // save dict-word in subcomp
                currSubcomp->isDictionaryWord = 1;
                currSubcomp = currSubcomp->next = newsubcomponent(); // dict-word in list, so get new subcomp
                cp += strlen(wordNode->word); // advance cp past extracted dict-word
                matchFlag = 1;
                break; // break out of inner-loop
            }
        }
        if (!matchFlag)  { // No dict-word found at cp      
            char oneNullTerminatedLetter[2] = { *cp++, '\0' }; // put 1st ltr into NULL-terminated string & adv cp.         
            strcat(currSubcomp->text, oneNullTerminatedLetter); // append letter-as-string to curr subcomp
        }
    }
    return subcomponents;
}

void
dumpDictionary(word_t *listhead) {
    printf("\nList of dictionary words:\n");
    printf("----------------\n");
    for (word_t *wordNode = listhead; wordNode != NULL; wordNode = wordNode->next) {
        printf("   %s\n", wordNode->word);
    }
    printf("----------------\n\n");
}

int 
main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int status;
    if ((status = loadDictionaryFromFile(DICTIONARY_FILEPATH, &dictionaryListhead)) < 0) {
        switch(status) {
        case FILE_NOT_FOUND:
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accessing dictionary: %s\n", argv[0]);
            break;
        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory");
            break;
        }
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Load dictionary first so we can show them the list of words if they didn't
     * pass in a command line argument with the word to parse.
     */    
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <word_to_parse>\n\n", argv[0]);
        dumpDictionary(dictionaryListhead);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    wordsubcomponent_t *subcomp = getWordSubcomponents(argv[1], dictionaryListhead);
    while(subcomp != NULL && strlen(subcomp->text) > 0) {
        if (subcomp->isDictionaryWord) 
            printf("\"%s\" ", subcomp->text);
        else
            printf("%s ", subcomp->text);
        subcomp = subcomp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: To read the code it's probably easier to paste it into your IDE or text editor and study it there.  This is a tricky task and does a lot, but if you really take your time to pick it apart and understand it you'll leap way ahead in your ability to program.

Answer (score 1):

@nerdist colony:
There is a resource leak in loadDictionaryFromFile. This means a file pointer was not closed when returning from this function in case of an error.

Here is a corrected copy of this function

```
int loadDictionaryFromFile(char *filename, word_t **listhead)
 {
    char wordFromFile[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
    word_t *lastWordStored = NULL;

    FILE *dictionaryFile = fopen(filename, "r"); 
    if (dictionaryFile == NULL) {
        return FILE_NOT_FOUND;
    }    
    while(fgets(wordFromFile, sizeof(wordFromFile), dictionaryFile)) {
        word_t *newDictionaryWordNode;
        if ((newDictionaryWordNode = calloc(sizeof(word_t), 1)) == NULL) { // calloc automatically zeroes memory
            fclose(dictionaryFile); // <-- Close the file pointer
            return OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        }
        char *cp = strchr(wordFromFile, '\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = '\0'; // get rid of trailing \n

        newDictionaryWordNode->word = strdup(wordFromFile);     
        if (*listhead == NULL) {
            lastWordStored = *listhead = newDictionaryWordNode;
        } else {
            lastWordStored = lastWordStored->next = newDictionaryWordNode;
        }
    }
    fclose(dictionaryFile);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```